# SPD workflow to reset check box

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, reset, unchecked, datefield

I have a sharepoint list that uses a cascading lookup to display items from another list in the first list.  I need to reset the checkbox on the item in the lookup display box in the every week beginning with a date in the "Start Date" field. Is it possible to construct a workflow in SPD to reset the checkbox every 7 days from the "Start Date"?

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like a "loop" using SharePoint designer (but actually what you do is delay for a while, then modify the item AND make another instance of the same workflow run when the item is modified). The technique is described here: http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/development/the-dog-ate-my-task-use-sharepoint-designer-to-email-daily-task-reminders